# How does "coding: pyxl" work in Python?

Tags: python

[pyxl](https://github.com/dropbox/pyxl) or [interpy](https://github.com/SyrusAkbary/interpy) are using a very interesting trick to enhance the python syntax in a way: `coding:` from [PEP-263](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/)

```
# coding: pyxl
print <html><body>Hello World!</body></html>
```

or

```
# coding: interpy
package = "Interpy"
print "Enjoy #{package}!"
```

How could I write my own `coding:` if I wanted to? And could I use more than one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm Syrus, the creator of `interpy`.

Thanks to codecs `# coding: your_codec_name` in Python we have a chance to preprocess the file before it is converted to *bytecode*.

This is how it works:

## Reading the file contents

At first, Python reads the file and *stores* its content. As the content could be encoded in a strange format, Python tries to **decode** it. Here is **where the magic happens**.

If the coding is not found, Python will try to decode the content with the default string coding: Ascii or UTF-8 codecs depending on the Python version. This is why you have to write `# coding: utf-8` when using unusual chars (á, ñ, Ð, ...) in Python 2, because Ascii is the default.

## Decoding file contents

If we [register a custom codec](https://github.com/SyrusAkbary/interpy/blob/master/interpy/codec/register.py#L54) (both encoder and decoder), and a file tells Python it is using our codec (via `# coding: codec_name`), then Python will decode the file with our codec.

#### Registering our codec

To register the codec without needing an import, we create a [path configuration file](https://github.com/SyrusAkbary/interpy/blob/master/interpy.pth) (.pth) which [registers](https://github.com/SyrusAkbary/interpy/blob/master/interpy/codec/register.py) the codec before any non-main-module is executed.

## Transforming file contents

Once the decoder of our [codec is called](https://github.com/SyrusAkbary/interpy/blob/master/interpy/codec/register.py#L25), we can modify the output we want, but... how do we know Python syntax (tokens) inside this content?

Simply call the [Python tokenizer](https://github.com/SyrusAkbary/interpy/blob/master/interpy/codec/tokenizer.py#L87) with the file contents and modify the desired tokens.

In the case of `interpy`, it changes the behavior only when [Python strings are found](https://github.com/SyrusAkbary/interpy/blob/master/interpy/codec/tokenizer.py#L98) in the file content.

## Sending back transformed (decoded) contents

Once we transform the content, we send it back to the Python compiler to be compiled to bytecode.

Hope you find this useful!